# How to pass the value to drop down fields in edit mode in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i have three Fields in my view.That three fields are drop down. I want to pass the value to these fields when edit button is clicked. That is the values need to pass to that drop down fields. My view is mentioned below

[image: DropDown]

In my view i have many drop downs but once i know how to pass the value to one drop down means i will do for another drop downs.

For Edit i create one view in sql and connect that view as EDMX file in my application.In this view(table) i have all fields which is in Visitors Form. That view name is View_VisitorsForm.

**My Model(VisitorsViewModel)**

```
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public System.Guid VisitingID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

**My Edit Code**

```
      public ActionResult Edit(Guid ?id)
      {
             WafeERPNEWEntities db = new WafeERPNEWEntities();
        SelectList typelist = new SelectList(db.Employees.ToList(), "EmployeeID", "DisplayName",  db.Employees);
        ViewData["EmployeeName"] = typelist;
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        VisitorsViewModel ObjVisitorsviewModel = new VisitorsViewModel();
        View_VisitorsForm visit = db.View_VisitorsForm.Find(id);
        visit.VisitingID = ObjVisitorsviewModel.VisitingID;
        visit.VisitingDate = ObjVisitorsviewModel.Date;
        visit.Description = ObjVisitorsviewModel.Description;
                 if (ObjVisitorsviewModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(ObjVisitorsviewModel);
    }
```

**My View Code**

```
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VisitingID)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VisitingID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VisitingID)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
        @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["EmployeeName"])
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
```

Now when i click the edit button  it pass the value to this line

```
    View_VisitorsForm visit = db.View_VisitorsForm.Find(id);
```

and also it getting  visit.visitingID. But it is not getting the value in  viewmodel .so the value will be empty in view.All values are empty VisitingID, Description, Date Fields are empty and in Employee drop down it won't show the value which i passed to this field it shows the first value in dropdown. so please any one tell me how to solve this issue. Actually I  try to explain my issue as per my level best and if you didn't understand my issue or any one need my full code  or need more code tell me . i ready to update my code again. but i need solution.

Advance Thanks..

Comment: _and in Employee drop down it won't show the value which i passed to this field_? You have not passed any value to the model! (no where do you ever set the value of `EmployeeID` in your controller)

Comment: Were you able to make things work correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeID,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["EmployeeName"])
```

The important part being "DropDownListFor". You are using "DropDownList".

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. If it is still not selecting the correct employee then you should make sure the EmployeeID of your model exists in the Employee List for your select list and that both have the same EmployeeID.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `DropDownList(...)` instead of a `DropDownListFor(...)`

**Your Model**

You must add a SelectList:

```
public SelectList Employees { get; set }
```

**Your Edit**

You must get your employees list and add it to your model:

```
// Get employees list from the database
var employees = db.Employee.Select(x => x.Id, x.Name).Tolist();

// Put the employees in a SelectList
var selectList = new SelectList(employees .Select(x => new { value = x.Id, text = x.Name }), "value", "text");}).ToList();

// Pass the list to your ViewModel
ObjVisitorsviewModel.Employees = selectList;
```

**Your View**

Finally, change your DropDownListFor line for this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeID,
                               model.Employees)
```

By using `DropDownList(...)`, your object data is not bound to the DropDown.  You must manage its selected value manually.

Comment: Maxime You said var employeesList = GetEmployees() like this . This means  var employeeList =db.Employee.Tolist(); like this??

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DropDownListFor` helper method.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeID,
                                    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["EmployeeName"])
```

Now in your GET action, you need to set the `EmployeeID` property value of your view model.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var objVisitorsviewModel = new VisitorsViewModel();
  // I am hard coding to 25. 
  // You may replace it with a valid Employee Id from your db table for the record
  ObjVisitorsviewModel.EmployeeID= 25; 

  return View(objVisitorsviewModel);
}
```

A more clean solution is to **not use ViewData** to transfer the data you need to render the dropdown option. You can make your code more strongly typed by simply adding a new property to your view model

```
public class VisitorsViewModel
{
   public List<SelectListItem> Employees { set;get;}
   public Guid? EmployeeID { get; set; }
   // Your existing properties goes here
}
```

Now in your GET action(create/edit), Instead of storing the data in ViewData, we will load to the Emp`enter code here`loyees property.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var  vm = new VisitorsViewModel();
  vm.Employees = db.Employees.Select(s=> new SelectListItem { 
                       Value=s.EmployeId.ToString(), Text=s.DisplayName }).ToList();
  return View(vm);
}
```

And in your view, we will use the DropDownListFor helper method with the Employees property

```
@model VisitorsViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.EmployeeID,Model.Employees,"Select")  
}
```

Comment: Shyju  i got this error in the line of    vm.Employees = db.Employees.Select(s=> new SelectListItem { 
                       Value=s.EmployeId.ToString(), Text=s.DisplayName }).ToList();    And the error is mentioned below .System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What is the type of `EmployeId` column ? If it is Guid, the code should work fine. I just verified it myself. You can call `ToString()` on a Guid property in a LINQ expression.