# How do i retrive dropdownlist using mymodel object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do i retrive in view dropdownlist using mymodel object

```
    List<object> mymodel = new List<object>();

        mymodel.Add(db.Events.ToList());
        mymodel.Add(db.Purposes.ToList());
        return View(mymodel);
```

Comment: retrieve from where?

Comment: in view to show dropdownlist

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/36602551/40521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a Model for your view and also implement few other **best practices** on the way. Various aspects of the solution will look like below:

1. In **Models** folder create a model for your view as below:

   ```
   public class MyViewModelClass
   {
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Events { get; set; }

       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Purposes { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. In your **Controller**, populate the model for the view and return it to the view as shown below. Note that you should select the two properties for the drop down list. "Value" which will be behind the scene value associated to each item in the drop down and "Text" which will be shown to the end user. Also note that I am returning SelectListItem which I can then later bind with the Drop down list.

   ```
   MyViewModelClass mymodel = new MyViewModelClass();

   mymodel.Events = db.Events.ToList().Select(x =>
                       new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Value = x.EventID.ToString(),
                           Text = x.EventName
                       });
   mymodel.Purposes = db.Purposes.ToList().Select(x =>
                       new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Value = x.PurposeID.ToString(),
                           Text = x.PurposeName
                       });

   return View(mymodel);
   ```
3. Now comes the last part, your **View**. You need to implement three things here:

   - Inform the view what kind of model to expect.
   - Create HTML form
   - Generate the Drop down list

The complete view will look like below for Events drop down:

```
    @model MyViewModelClass

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

    <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Events,Model.Events,"--select--")
    }
    </div>
```

Comment: where is come from SelectlistItem in model class

Comment: SelectListItem is nothing but just an inbuilt class in MVC especially for the drop down list. It is nothing but a pair of two parts, i.e **value**, which you want to bind to your drop down item and **text** which you want to display. Whatever data you have, can work with this class. See the controller code. I am dynamically generating the SelectListItem for the model using simple syntax. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: error in selectlistitem item in model class                                             public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Events { get; set; }

Comment: Make sure you have referenced System.Web.Mvc in your project. Also there should be a using statement to include the dll in your ViewModel class: ***using System.Web.Mvc***. Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: thnks brother. Yeah i' m missing the referenced

Comment: That's great! If this helped please do mark this as the answer. There will be a tick mark right below the voting arrows beside the answer. If you need further help do let me know.

Comment: Plz help this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753367/how-do-i-retrive-dropdownlist-using-mymodel-object