# How to retrieve dropdown list using dynamic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Dropdroplist retrieving problem:

```
   public ActionResult About()

    {
        ViewBag.Purpose = new SelectList(db.Purposes, "purpose");

        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        obj.dua = db.Duass.ToList();
        return View(obj);
    }
```

In View Section

> @using MockUp.Models
>
> @model dynamic
>
> @Html.DropDownList("Purpose", "select")

Output Error occurs:

[image]

Comment: **Don't** use dynamic!

Comment: And you error has got nothing to do with using dynamic anyway - you have not use the correct overload - `ViewBag.Purpose = new SelectList(db.Purposes, "purpose", "purpose");` assuming your model contains a property named `purpose` which you want to use for both the options `value` attribute and display text.

Comment: how can we  write in view section  dropdownlist

Comment: Plz help this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753367/how-do-i-retrive-dropdownlist-using-mymodel-object