# How to get list of objects which have id from session state and show it in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have 2 tables in database

```
Subject(subjID, subjName, tchID)
Teacher(tchID, tchName)
```

How to get list of subjects which have `tchID` value from Sesstion state and show it in `dropdownlist`?
My controller:

```
 public ActionResult GetListSubj()
    {
        db = new DatabaseMng();
        Teacher tch = db.Teachers.Find(Session["tchID"].ToString());
        ViewBag.subjID = new SelectList(db.Subjects, "subjID", "subjName");
        return View();
    }
```

In view:

...

```
@Html.DropDownList("subjID", String.Empty)
```

This is my code, it's not complete, because it return all subjects, but I want subjects have `tchID` from Session state in Login View:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Teacher model, FormCollection f)
    {
        db = new DatabaseMng();
        string id = f["txtID"];
        string pw= f["txtPass"];
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {            
                Session["tchID"] = id;
                return RedirectToAction("GetListSubj", "Teacher"); 
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are creating the `SelectList` object using `db.Subjects` which is all the items in the Subject table.

Include a where clause when querying `db.Subjects`. You can use the value from session for your where clause.

```
var idFromSession = string.empty;
if (Session["tchID"] != null)
{
    idFromSession = Session["tchID"].ToString();
}
var filterdSubjects = db.Subjects.Where(s=>s.tchID == idFromSession);
// Use filterdSubjects  to build your dropdown.
```

Assuming `tchID` property is of string type. If it is numeric type(*Int32/Int64*), convert your session value to numeric type and use that in your where clause.

```
var idFromSession = 0;
if (Session["tchID"] != null)
{
    idFromSession = Convert.ToInt32(Session["tchID"]);
}
var filterdSubjects = db.Subjects.Where(s=>s.tchID==idFromSession);
```

You might also consider to switch to a more robust [strongly typed approach which uses view models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600458/how-to-pass-the-value-to-drop-down-fields-in-edit-mode-in-mvc4/36602551#36602551) to transfer data from your action methods to view rather than relying on dynamic stuff like ViewBag/ViewData.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: But what about View? Because it's error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Read the Session value out side of that linq expression to a variable ( like i did in second example) and use that.